# Are there other way(xmlns) to it with DOMDOcument?

Tags: php

I have example.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02"> 
      <content>

 <books>    
     <book>
  <qty>12</qty>
  <title>C++</title>
     </book>
     <book>
  <qty>21</qty>
  <title>PHP</title>
     </book>    
   </books>    
  </content>
</Document>
```

Currently I did like (with file)

```
  $xmlFile = file_get_contents("example.xml");
  $xml = str_replace('<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.02"> ', "<Document>", $xmlFile); // This removes ALL default namespaces.
  //echo $xmlFile;
  $fp = fopen('example.xml', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $xml);
  fclose($fp);
  //TODO MORE AFTER IT
```

Are there other way(Remove the xmlns) to it with  DOMDOcument?
Because I am using read/write file.

Comment: Another way to do what exactly? Removing the XML namespace?

Comment: yes by using DOMDOcument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this but based on the docs, this might work:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('example.xml');
$dom->documentElement->removeAttribute("xmlns");
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

Not a very clean solution, but it might work if you are really just trying to get rid of the xmlns attribute.

Comment: What is coresponding for my xml

Comment: I assumed you already had the dom, after all you asked very specifically about using DOMDocument. I edited the comment above, but I don't have time to test it with real XML - but I think that would be the only way. By the way, it is a slower method than your string replace since it involves parsing it into a DOM.